# Yii mysql transaction: data saving only in one table

Tags: php, yii, transactions, mysql-workbench

I am very new to Yii. I was trying something like this--

```
  public function actionCreate()

{
    $a=new Tblcompany;
            $b= new Tblusergroup;

  $transaction= Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();

try{
    if(isset($_POST['Tblcompany']))
    {

                    $a->attributes=$_POST['Tblcompany'];

        if($a->save()){

         $b->company_code= $a->company_code;

                  $b->usergroup_code='Admin';

                  $b->save();

                      $transaction->commit();


            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$a->company_code));

            }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
    'a'=>$a,
            'b'=>$b,
    ));

 }catch(Exception $error){

  $transaction->rollback();
    }

}
```

don't know why no data is being saved in tblusergroup. Although data is perfectly added in tblcompany..Kindly help please :/

Comment: It seems the code is ok, put $b->save() in try_catch statement to see everything is OK.

Comment: You should redirect only if $b->save() return true and transaction commited.

Comment: hmm...yah.i was just thinking why no data was going inside b. Didn't go thoroughly about other stuffs.TY neway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your $b model failed validation.

Put

```
var_dump($b->getErrors());
die();
```

just after `$b->save();` and see the errors. It must be empty array in order to save the model to DB.

Comment: comes with this message, which show it's empty..

array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: dunno what happened, but after doing that; i removed that part (var_dump($b->getErrors());die();) and i ran the code, it suddenly worked  fine. Thanx a lot :)